# Error in : NA/NaN argument

Tags: r, rest, httr

Below is my GET request

```
    req <- GET(url, add_headers(
  c(
    "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0",
    "Accept":"application/vnd.subdomain.domain.v2+json",
    "Authorization":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJRb2QteEVlSDJNQXJKVjZSRkVoM2g3ZUZ6SGhmMGFPbGphOXJ2SHJld3pBIn0.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.Hhy-V-VJKTNmIxX9hjT49TRSj8ofEMBTCrFZi-TzhJMA01i1aRnoS26UlGQTTr2OPI3OJ5lFpsdjkTXECXuc1IzVoUBqalR3XhAdtA0kRvEtrmAlptESjvQF-NOcVJoO-pXmy_P2fncvjdllacdtQm8_jOpDAaa7IgjNLXHt8g8GsZblBP06w9ETw8sMy1FalB9_u3HTTul2TlK0fEuaREtTC0szIYW7AefhaDseRPo0N-57otAT3zr_dorY0SamYbG1gHsjGMZ5mY4IEeYLbh--5WKPrt5vo9i1GertUuFLGftuofQM2xQTHGBKaNcd4S5SghJvtRCOaU3-5rlz8w",
    "expires_in":300,
    "refresh_expires_in":1800,
    "refresh_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJRb2QteEVlSDJNQXJKVjZSRkVoM2g3ZUZ6SGhmMGFPbGphOXJ2SHJld3pBIn0.eyJqdGkiOiI3OTVmNTExMC1jNWJjLTQ5MDItOTI4Yy1kMGU5ZDFlOTAwMzUiLCJleHAiOjE1MjAyNTIwMjksIm5iZiI6MCwiaWF0IjoxNTIwMjUwMjI5LCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvZ2luLmFrdm8ub3JnL2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL2Frdm8iLCJhdWQiOiJjdXJsIiwic3ViIjoiOGQyYmJmNTYtYTI3Zi00NDgyLWIzMDYtMjRkNTY3NjhhM2E2IiwidHlwIjoiUmVmcmVzaCIsImF6cCI6ImN1cmwiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjAsInNlc3Npb25fc3RhdGUiOiJmOTgwMzg3YS0yZDcxLTQzODUtYmE0NC00NWZhMzQ2YjM2ODMiLCJjbGllbnRfc2Vzc2lvbiI6IjJlNDNhNGJmLTUyM2YtNDk1Yy04NDY1LTQ5Y2FkNTY2ZGNjNiIsInJlYWxtX2FjY2VzcyI6eyJyb2xlcyI6WyJha3ZvOmx1bWVuOnRyaWFsOmFkbWluIiwiYWt2bzpsdW1lbjp3YXRlcnNoZWRrZW55YTphZG1pbiIsImFrdm86bHVtZW46ZXRoaW9waWE6YWRtaW4iLCJha3ZvOmx1bWVuOmV0aGlvcGlhIiwiYWt2bzpsdW1lbjpkZW1vIiwiYWt2bzpsdW1lbjpmb290YmFsbGZvcndhdGVyIiwiYWt2bzpsdW1lbjpmb290YmFsbGZvcndhdGVyOmFkbWluIiwiYWt2bzpsdW1lbjp3YXRlcnNoZWRrZW55YSIsInVtYV9hdXRob3JpemF0aW9uIiwiYWt2bzpsdW1lbjp0cmlhbCJdfSwicmVzb3VyY2VfYWNjZXNzIjp7ImFjY291bnQiOnsicm9sZXMiOlsibWFuYWdlLWFjY291bnQiLCJtYW5hZ2UtYWNjb3VudC1saW5rcyIsInZpZXctcHJvZmlsZSJdfX19.Ap70GlrcrPc9KToTY4RjumL1bFBnjaic-jJ6eQmd8mp-gz18Zn93VpUXRf52wQ3UoBnYFMVW2fxfVRO0bp2JXy3-iOYTzhmSrzh3rBccWVep5sdCCj3rvfiBLI7ExD-U8pwpMdm1cHDDxzh9IyM-qxM2DsNkTl1NVaIF-zd1YtVa3pc09A7i2lDNm4QuHBQyYkOWxkgnbiPNKyBO4CO_KfSkamGvWvtXwODWjvTk-yGCQ22iH3vCSOzckcVAQxcGUgTA6T0jeuO7tw0tS0YQaTlhKseQ5bwZU1JqUUf-kIwk_r85gT-ifxGTPNCjMbxaXlRWCSKQPKxV110DL1CJcg",
    "token_type":"bearer",
    "id_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJRb2QteEVlSDJNQXJKVjZSRkVoM2g3ZUZ6SGhmMGFPbGphOXJ2SHJld3pBIn0.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.Kc_WNwU5MfnC5MOkICZIzReGBLlUtoP-FHWDQLAlLGaf1DI47Z7AM4RqB9-0huwULQOx6WC1Js4NfVnjrFHl7y9qs9Z1zLJF41HJewCYBXlHwthv3UUNRAhniYW2b7_QMmOKcJ8pI6ZYYNMwHovLSIqlfLDF9Pt5X-z3s7IZEvxj7Cui6hOxQF8miDWcrDbabIi9ypNk2dN5kE5w8gvlxx4tI9vwJ0kgMMDcWGP4Dpj_1xdB3ZA6Y_X8mXNy5tJ8pbaGCagf7nrXyGzZxKer4K__IU8XxRzE2DfBrQoDFXpc7EvIHH8YUusPp6eGnT6InC9dDjKD7X7v1eXitDQVzw",
    "not-before-policy":0,
    "session_state":"f980387a-2d71-4385-ba44-45fa346b3683"
  )
))
```

With the `url`, I'm fetching an endpoint that doesn't have a query. 
However, on the console, I get this error.

```
    Error in "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0" : 
  NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In request(headers = c(..., .headers)) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In request(headers = c(..., .headers)) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

What could be wrong with my `GET` request? Have I coded it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from the use of the `:` sequence operator with strings.

```
c("a":"b")
Error in "a":"b" : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: NAs introduced by coercion 
2: NAs introduced by coercion
```

`add_headers` is expecting named values so you should use:

```
add_headers(
    "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0",
...
)
```